# Cygwin cron reads bash_profile but not bashrc

Tags: bash, cron, environment-variables, cygwin

I am trying to a run a cronjob on my Windows machine with Cygwin that needs access to environment variables that I have defined in my ~/.bashrc. Here all the different things I have tried to get it to access the env variable:

1. Simple sourcing of bashrc

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
SHELL=/usr/bin/bash
*/1 * * * * source ~/.bashrc ; env | grep "MAP60"
```

2. Invoking bash and running the command

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
SHELL=/usr/bin/bash
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc ; env | grep MAP60"
```

3. Trying a bash login shell

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
SHELL=/usr/bin/bash
 */1 * * * * /usr/bin/bash -lc " source ~/.bashrc ; env | grep MAP60"
```

None of these work, but case 3 works if I add the variable to my ~/.bash_profile. I have also tried sourcing the bashrc with the full path, and also using . instead of source to invoke the file. I've also tried just sourcing the bash_profile directly like in case 1, but that doesn't work either. I would like to have the variables be called in the ~/.bashrc rather than having to call a login shell each time. How can I achieve that with cygwin cron?

Comment: Is it possible your .bashrc errors out or skips sections in non-interactive mode? Have you tried capturing error output from the cron job? How about `/usr/bin/bash -lc " set -x; source ~/.bashrc ; env | grep MAP60" 2>/tmp.error.log`

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (and everyone else). So something is wrong with your setup. I don't have cron setup on Cygwin but one, very likely, possibility is that it can't email you the output of the command (something that is usually the default on a real UNIX). Start by modifying your third example thusly:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/bash -xlc " source ~/.bashrc ; env | grep MAP60" >/tmp/x 2>&1
```

Then check the contents of */tmp/x*.

Note: Bash only reads *~/.bashrc* for interactive shells. Using `-l` does not make the shell interactive. Putting var definitions in *~/.bashrc* is not recommended. But if you want to do this you should ensure any command that should only run if the shell is interactive is inside a `if [[ $- = *i* ]]; then ...; fi` block in your *~/.bashrc*.

Comment: Hi @Kurtis Rader, the cron is able to send me emails without an issue, and every time I ran one of the examples that I posted in my question without the grep, I could see all the env variables and it was clear that my variable was not being pulled here. I should have added that to my question. In cron on most unix systems, sourcing the bashrc or bash_profile before calling the script will let you load those variables but not on Cygwin. I wasn't aware that the bashrc is for interactive shells only - now it makes sense why it was not reading my bashrc despite making it a login shell. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "my variable was not being pulled here." Do you mean it wasn't in the `env` output? Or that it is in the environment and the `grep` isn't matching that line? Also, if you do the experiment I suggested what is in */tmp/x*? What is in your *~/.bashrc*? Or, if that's too big, what statement(s) cause var `MAP60` to be defined?

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous comment, I ran each of the examples without the grep and MAP60 wasn't in the `env` output and not being pulled from the bashrc file. MAP60 is defined with a very generic `export` command, which is definitely not the problem. Your experiment just gives an empty /tmp/x file, which was expected considering the variable isn't being loaded from the bashrc in the first place.

Comment: No, it is not expected that */tmp/x* is empty. At a minimum you should have these two lines: `+ source /Users/krader/.bashrc` and `+ env` along with the output of `env`.

Comment: My apologies - I was running `/usr/bin/bash -xlc " source ~/.bashrc ; env | grep MAP60 > /tmp/x"  2>&1` , which is clearly not the same as what you suggested. It looks like it is sourcing my bashrc, but I don't see any output for the `grep`. Does this line  `readonly PROFILEREAD=true` make a difference? I'm not sure if that variable would cause an issue with bashrc being sourced correctly.